# Automatically maintain daily log files in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create automatically log files on daily basis for one month and after that old files will be unlinked itself. Following is my code. Am i doing right. If yes then is there any way to reduces filesize on disk.

```
 $KeepDays = 30;  # how many days of log files we'll keep on hand
    $logname  = date("Ymd") . '.status.log';
    $OldFile  = date('Ymd',mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d") - ($KeepDays + 1)),date("Y"))) . '.status.log';
    if (file_exists($OldFile)) { unlink($OldFile); } # erase oldest log file 

    if (file_exists('logs/'.$logname)) {
        $fp=fopen('logs/'.$logname,'a');
    }else{
        $fp=fopen('logs/'.$logname,'w');
    }
    $chunk = "Var1_".$var1.'_'.$Var2.' var3_'.$var3.' var_'.$var.' var_'.$var4 ;
    fwrite($fp,$chunk. PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fp);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This queston should be asked at Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think it's going to work. You basically remove oldfile and do not get its contents. Wherea re all those $var1 etc defined? Is there any kind of loop?

```
$KeepDays = 30;  # how many days of log files we'll keep on hand
$logname  = date("Ymd") . '.status.log';
// Would give '20141118.status.log ' for example

$OldFile  = date('Ymd',mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d") - ($KeepDays + 1)),date("Y"))) . '.status.log';
// Would give '20141018.status.log' for example

if (file_exists($OldFile)) { unlink($OldFile); } # erase oldest log file 
// Remove old file, but you remove it and can't get it's contents anymore. So you delete it wihtout copying its contents anywhere

if (file_exists('logs/'.$logname)) {
    $fp=fopen('logs/'.$logname,'a');
}else{
    $fp=fopen('logs/'.$logname,'w');
}
$chunk = "Var1_".$var1.'_'.$Var2.' var3_'.$var3.' var_'.$var.' var_'.$var4 ;
// Where are all those $var* defined? What you put here?


fwrite($fp,$chunk. PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

Additionally, you can zip or gzip contents of file.